# How to save a texture paint material as png image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export, image, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I made a texture with Texture Paint, but it didn't work out as expected, so I want to edit it in Photoshop, but when I want to open it in Photoshop a error message is shown.
Here is how I tried to save it as png file: UV/Image Editor > Image > Safe as Image
Like I told you, it didn't work. Could somebody tell me, what I'm doing wrong? Is there even a way to do this?

Comment: What error message is shown? What didn't work when saving? Saving via Image > Save As Image is the way to save from UV editor. Show screenshots and more details of what went wrong

Comment: When I want to open it in Photoshop, a message, which says, that this is a Picture Format, which can't be opened. Shows up.

Comment: Can you try a different image format and see if you get the same error?

Comment: What file format do you save into in Blender? More details?

Comment: Well, I saved it as a png Image and now I also tried to save it as jpg, but it still doesn't work. But I don't Need to save the Image anymore, because I could fix it in Blender.
Thank you anyway